# Is there any way to display an image as background?

Tags: media

I have a picture in a field and I want to be displayed in its exact look but as a CSS background... is this even possible? Is there any mechanism how does that?

Comment: Have you look _at all_ at how to control css output with Drupal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Background Images](https://www.drupal.org/project/bg_image) and [Background Images Formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/bg_image_formatter) modules to achieve this. Note in the Background Images Formatter description that it can take images from a field and add it to the background.

Otherwise you can create your own module that generates the appropriate css and adds it to the page with [drupal_add_css](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/7)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you'd have to add it to your theme.

Alternatively, you could use [CSS Injector](https://www.drupal.org/project/css_injector).